# byte array image src nativescript

Tags: nativescript-angular

In nativescript(with angular) is there any way to set the src of an image from the response of a web api call that returns the image as byte array/base64? 
There is not to much documentation, and I need to see the html and .ts files from a simple example, I have no code to paste here now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to first create `ImageSource` form base64 string and then assign that imageSource to Image Native Element.

```
let imageSource = new ImageSource();
let loadedSource64 = imageSource.loadFromBase64(BASE_64_STRING_FROM_API_CALL);
if (loadedSource64 ) {
    let image= <Image>this.imageElement.nativeElement;
    image.imageSource = this.imageSource;
}
```

Comment: `loadedSource64` is true, and it seems that the `imageSource` has a value (width and height are correct), but nothing happens on the screen, the image is not shown

Comment: update: it was my fault, the `imageElement` in my case was not the right object